# Get WebStorm to recognize back-end and front-end JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

How can I configure my **WebStorm** project to get autocomplete working properly on my back-end and front-end code?

I can enable **node.js** support in the entire project and install definitions for my `node_modules`, but I would like to disable it for my `public/` folder for example, and make it autocomplete with ES5 syntax and be aware of dependencies installed in my `bower_components`.

Is that possible without using separate projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define scopes for your libraries. There is a `Usage Scope` button next to Node.js Core Library in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM` - you can use to limit the Node.js support to your server-side code. Same for node_modules - once added as a project library in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`, they can be configured to be applied to certain files/folders only using `Manage Scopes` button. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/04/easier-javascript-library-scope-configuration-in-intellij-idea-111/